# how to check if container is up to date

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm using docker-compose to mange my container 'abc' in a linux server (centos).

my steps that I want to perofrm:

1) docker compose pull 'abc' in order to pull my latest image

```
docker-compose --file docker-compose.yml pull
```

2) docker command to check if my container 'abc' need to be updated (**possible**???)

3) if my container 'abc'  I will perform docker-compose up -d

```
docker-compose --file docker-compose.yml up -d
```

Remark: I know that step 3 is checking and than update the container if necessary but I need to perform pre tasks if step 2 return True

Comment: This seems related:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37685581/how-to-get-docker-compose-to-use-the-latest-image-from-repository

Comment: thanks @TheGameiswar for your messgae but I didn't find there any command for my step 2

Comment: AS per this ,it is not implemented..:https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3574

Comment: read out all those comments  in above link

Comment: What kind of pre-task do you want to do? That sounds wrong somehow...

Comment: @TheGameiswar - I didn't find any mention there for what i'm looking for

Comment: @jonasheinisch - several pre tasks such as: disable the host in my f5 pool load balancer, run a script and more...

Comment: You could do something like this to check the if the container is using the latest image id. ```CONTAINER_IMAGE_SHA=docker container inspect $CONTAINER_NAME -f "{{ .Image }}"
  LATEST_IMAGE_SHA=docker image inspect $IMAGE_NAME -f "{{ .Id }}"```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if this will do exactly what you need, but you can try to check if your container needs updating like this:

`docker-compose` puts a label with a hash of the current configuration into the container config. You can get the configuration hash like this:

```
docker inspect my-container -f '{{index .Config.Labels "com.docker.compose.config-hash"}}'
```

You can then compare this hash to the hash of your *current* docker compose file:

```
docker-compose config --hash="my-container"
```

If those hashes differ, the containers probably needs to be rebuild as the configuration has changed.

This will however probably not work if you're using the `latest` tag and the image itself needs updating. To account for that, you could additionally try [How do I check if my local docker image is outdated, without pushing from somewhere else?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42137511/how-do-i-check-if-my-local-docker-image-is-outdated-without-pushing-from-somewh) or [Bash parse docker status to check if local image is up to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44739538/bash-parse-docker-status-to-check-if-local-image-is-up-to-date)

Answer (score 3):

To restate your question as I read it:

> Prior to updating a container, do X

Changes Include:

- Image changes
- Environment changes for containers
- Networking changes
- ..etc

**TLDR;** What you want is a `dry-run` feature of `docker-compose`. You are not alone: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1203

**More;** I think you are out of luck trying to use `docker-compose` itself for this purpose until this issue is tackled by the developer community. To be completely safe you would want to perform your pre-flight action when anything affecting the running container is about to change.

**Potential Direction:** If we were to wish for this, we'd build a shell script that does the examination for us, as simple as a diff on the compose file, or more complex as locating each image e.g., `grep image docker-compose.yml | sed "s/^.*\: \(.*\),$/\1/g"` ... etc and so forth.